# Django import code from other apps

Tags: python, django, nameerror

I have a project whith multiple apps. 
So when I want some code from another app I use

```
from app.pyfile import *
```

or

```
from app.pyfile import specific_function
```

To be more specific: 
I have an app called 'commonapp' where I have some common stuff that I use in all the other apps. In this app I have a common.py file where I have some functions, including a function called `my_response(request,template,context)` ,which is the one causes a **NameError**. Now this particular function is always being called inside other functions.

for example:

```
from commonapp.common import *

def myInfo(request):
    context = {}
    data = ''
    data =  SomeModel.objects.all()
    template = 'path/to/info.html'
    context['data'] = data
    a = my_response(request,template,context)
    return a
```

This raises a **NameError "global name my_response is not defined"**

I know what a NameError is, but why here? I would expect an ImportError if something could not be imported or even "global name a is not defined" .

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a screenshot showing where the `my_response(request,template,context)` is and the file structure of the app.

[image]

Comment: Er, what? You get a NameError because my_response is not defined there or imported from common. What do you not understand about that?

Comment: When I try to do `from commonapp.common import my_response` I get an ImportError. I can't understand how that is possible when all the other things I have imported from other apps are being imported just fine.

Comment: But both of those errors show that `commonapp.common` does not contain a function called `my_response`. How is that not clear? Maybe you should show that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
from commonapp.common import *
```

everything that can be imported from the package is imported into current global namespace. Apparently `my_response` is not imported (for some reason).
So, you get `NameError`, because `my_response` is resolved at point of it's execution, i.e. in

```
# Python tries to lookup `my_response` in local and then global context
# But, it can't find it, thus NameError exception occurs. 
a = my_response(request,template,context)
```

And `ImportError`s are generally raised by importing routines e.g `from package import non_existing_function` and are not encountered in other context.

Comment: Ok, when you import a function from another file ,isn't that suppose to be in the global contex? 
If i import my_response() inside the def myInfo() it works just fine... 
So it cannot be imported in global but in can be imported in local function ? I don't get it. I mean how models from other apps are imported?

Comment: It might be that you have a circular import problem, i.e. commonapp.common imports the file which contains `myInfo()` directly or indirectly through more nested imports. Also note, that doing start imports, like `from package import *` is considered a bad practice and should be avoided unless you truly understand why exactly you need to import everything.

Comment: I've thought about that, but Ican't seem to find the connection. The myInfo() is on another app,in a custom file as well, not nested in ListView for example. It's just a function that gets some data drom a specific model. The my_response() is supposed to be my "passepartout" function for rendering templates. It worked with Django 1.5 .This happened when I migrated to 1.8.
And I don't do the import * much often. I tried it here cause I had the error.

Comment: Ensure that you are importing the correct file. First, remove all *.pyc files, then open django shell, import commonapp and check it's `__file__` attribute. Is the path correct? Next, try importing `my_response`. As a rule - if you can do it in shell, then it should work in code.

Comment: I get an error because of circular import problem indeed, when I try to import my_response directly. If I do import * ..it obciously bypasses it and the original template renders correctly

Comment: It was a circular problem!!!!! Shell made it clear !! Thank you so much!!! I was going crazy!!